# Back up complete or fail notification in sql server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (X64) Microsoft Corporation Enterprice Edition (64-bit)

i need to create a job for the SQL database to backup everyday is working fine.

i want **email alert for jobs completed or fails**.

In that what are the **steps** i want to do.

help me.

Comment: Within a job you create your backup task, then create a send email for success task and a send email for failure task, and configure the success to run on the success of the backup task, and the failure to run on the failure of the backup task.  Have you looked at the create job wizard in management studio?

Comment: how to  configure the success to run on the success of the backup task, and the failure to run on the failure of the backup task.

Comment: You can use SqlBak it will and tune email notification which will send you emails in the case of success/failure of your job. Just take a look here: http://sqlbak.com/blog/sql-server-backup-email-notification/

Answer (score 3):

Create a Job using the wizard.

Under steps, add backup, success email and failure email tasks (you can populate them now or not).  Go back into the backup step and hit edit.  The go to the Advanced page and here you can set which tasks to run on success or failure.